# How to really know the last version of a jar using Maven display-dependency-updates

Tags: maven, dependency-management, apache-commons-beanutils

Maven provides a plugin (versions-maven-plugin) that allows to retrieve the latest available versions for all the dependencies of a project.

However, the result is polluted by dependencies when their naming scheme has evolved over time.

Perfect example of this is commons-beanutils. I get this result in Maven:

```
    [INFO] --- versions-maven-plugin:2.5:display-dependency-updates (default-cli) @ dataimport ---
    [INFO] The following dependencies in Dependencies have newer versions:
    [INFO]   commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils ......... 1.9.3 -> 20030211.134440
```

The **real** last version (as of this writing) is 1.9.3, but back in 2003, version number was based on a timestamp.

Is there a workaround that would allow the Maven plugin to get the real last version? By ignoring a range of versions?

Until I find a solution, I can't reasonably use the Maven feature allowing to automatically update all dependencies.

Googling about this problem, it looks like no one complains about it - and as a result the version 20030211.134440 is still heavily used while quite old.

Answer (score 1):

You can use parameter *rulesUrl* to pass to this plugin path to file with rules of version comparision.

See http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/use-latest-versions-mojo.html#rulesUri .

Format of this file you can see there: http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/rule.html .

Comment: Many thanks! Looking at the GIT issue related to this feature (which is currently marked for deprecation), I even found the exact rule to use. See https://github.com/mojohaus/versions-maven-plugin/issues/157.